# What Are the body trim Specs of this 2000 Jeep Wrangler

Tags: jeep, wrangler

So im in the Market of a old 2000 Jeep wrangler i found in a friends backyard. so i have some pictures of it and im punching in the info into my amazon garage, now there are a few options like this:

[image: Amazon garage vehicle info]

i have a few pictures and i only need the body trim but idk which it is. do any of you know?

any additional information on anything else is helpful too.

## Pictures

i couldn't upload them but i have a video on my channel with them:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3XCgpRA-Ghw

Comment: It might be easiest to get the VIN# from your friend's Jeep and call a Jeep dealer.  With this information the Jeep dealer should be able to tell you the trim style as well as other questions/information you may have like transmission type, etc.  The VIN# is located on the left corner (driver side) of the dashboard where the windshield and dashboard meet.  It is easiest to see looking from outside the vehicle.

Comment: What are the options shown under "Trim"? I see Sahara. Most often with a Wrangler (and most every other type of Jeep), if there is a trim/option package installed, they put a decal on the vehicle specifying it. Like Sahara or Rubicon. They are pretty proud of those things :o)

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 there's sahara, Sport and SE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be an SE if anything. (I was finally able to see the video.) Sahara is a special edition which has specific graphics on it, which this one does not have. A Sport would have the decals on it in several places. The SE would be the only other one which it could be. To be quite honest with you, it really shouldn't matter too much in the long run, if the reasoning for getting this information into a system where it'd help you find parts or what have you. The reason why I state this is because most of the parts are going to be the same throughout the trim levels. Only things like the engine, which there are two available (I4 and I6) stock. I couldn't see what *exactly* the engine is, but if the graphics on the fan shroud mean anything, it might have a transplant in it. If so, all bets are off anyways.